# Generate and Display dynamic UI using for loop in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am taking dataframe as input and adding few extra columns in it. Then I am using for loop to do the processing for each row. This processing takes time, so I want to display processed rows as separate ui elements.

For example,
if 1st row is being processed then,

```
ROW-1
```

if 2nd row is being processed then it will be added next ROW-1

```
ROW-1
ROW-2
```

so as my for loop is progressing through rows, the latest processed row will be added in the list as UI element.

I have used lapply but it processes all the rows and then displays everything together.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ui1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Init_vals <- 1:5
  for(i in 1:5){
Sys.sleep(5)
    output[[paste("ui",i,sep="")]] = renderUI({
        list(
          fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
              textInput(
                inputId=paste0("id",i) ,
                label = "here",
                value = Init_vals[i]
              )
            )
          ),
          uiOutput(paste("ui",i + 1,sep=""))
        )
        
      })
  }

    
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here, you can see that only last ui element is generated and other elements from ui1 to ui4 are skipped! Every 5 seconds app should generate new text input.

[image]

Comment: You should use `lapply`, see example at https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html

Answer (score 1):

Like Jim suggested, try using `lapply` instead of a `for` loop:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
        Sys.sleep(5)
        output[[paste0("ui", i)]] <- renderUI({
            list(
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  textInput(
                    inputId = paste0("id", i),
                    label = "here",
                    value = i
                  )
                )
              ),
              uiOutput(paste0("ui", i + 1))
            )
        })
    })
}
```

Seems like there is something unique about shiny which prevents output being correctly assigned a `for` loop. You could also use [`purrr::walk()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html)

EDIT:
You are correct that `shiny` waits to display everything until the `server` function is done running. I believe this is how `shiny` is designed -- the dynamic UI elements (created with `renderUI`) will **not** be displayed until they are **all** done being created.

You might want to use [`withProgress()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html) instead, if your goal is to inform your users how long the process might take:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  withProgress(
    message = 'Calculation in progress',
    detail = 'This may take a while...',
    value = 0, 
    expr = {
      lapply(1:5, function(i) {
        Sys.sleep(5)
        output[[paste0("ui", i)]] <- renderUI({
          list(
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                textInput(
                  inputId = paste0("id", i),
                  label = "here",
                  value = i
                )
              )
            ),
            uiOutput(paste0("ui", i + 1))
          )
        })
        incProgress(1 / 5)
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: in your lapply as well as my approach it completes the process (25 seconds) and displays the output altogether. same thing happens with my approach. I want to create each element after 5 seconds or when that iteration is completed in for loop.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your use case a little better now. See my updated answer

Comment: I already have this feature but I want to display ui elements as they are processed by for loop. For example, If I have dataframe of 10 rows and I am using for loop to process it, I want to show 1st row as it is being done processing, then I'll 2nd row down to 1st row, then 3rd row and this way all 10 rows will be displayed one by one.

Comment: I want to do this because all the rows will have ui elements as well. and it will ask user for input via prompt if any information is missing during for processing. I cant achieve this with for loop or lapply as none of them will show completed rows on the go or allow me to generate prompts during for loop processing. Can you suggest some framework with reactivity or how can  I use reactive Values to construct for loop logic. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I understand your use case, but I think it would require hacking `shiny` to an extent that I don't think I can provide you. You might consider creating custom javascript code if you want this much control over the rendering of your elements